# xmlstarlet - order alternate pairs of tag values

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

With the this XML

```
<a>
<b>1</b>
<c>2</c>
<b>3</b>
<c>4</c>
</a>
```

I would like this output from xmlstarlet:

```
1 2
3 4
```

But with this command:

```
xml sel -T -t -m /a -v b -v c -n
```

I get:

```
1
32
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was making it too complicated:

```
xml sel -T -t -m /a/* -v . -o " " -i "name()=\"c\"" -n -b test.xml
```

So that's: always print out the value of the child of `a`, print a space, and if this tag is `c` then print a new line.

Comment: XPath treats single quotes the same as double quotes, so you can use `"name()='c'"`